# Ionic 3 how to filter array nested in 2 *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I would like to filter `day.children` `name` property based on search input. Having difficulties with that nested *ngFor because one relies on second. `dayOverViewByGroup` is comming from API.
I tried to wrap `day.children` in a function like `filterIt(day.children)` but I got infinite loop. Thank you.

I have following(simplified) html structure

```html
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Suchen..." (ionInput)="searchChildren($event)" padding></ion-searchbar>
<ion-grid *ngFor="let day of dayOverViewByGroup; let i = index" padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let child of day.children; let j = index">
  <h1>{{child.name}}</h1>
</ion-grid>
```

dayOverview variable example data from API

```js
// dayOverview variable example data from API

[
  {
    "name": "Kindergarden 1",
    "presence_id": 25,
    "totalChildren": 3,
    "totalCheckinChildren": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "daycareComment": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "id": "10633",
        "away": null,
        "checkin": [],
        "additionalDay": false,
        "remarks": "",
        "awayClass": "",
        "reason": "",
        "addtionalClass": "",
        "disableToggle": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "checkout": "Nicht anwesend",
        "class": "notcheckin"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "daycareComment": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "id": "8322",
        "away": null,
        "checkin": [],
        "additionalDay": false,
        "remarks": "",
        "awayClass": "",
        "reason": "",
        "addtionalClass": "",
        "disableToggle": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "checkout": "Nicht anwesend",
        "class": "notcheckin"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bastian Paper",
        "daycareComment": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "id": "86999",
        "away": null,
        "checkin": [],
        "additionalDay": false,
        "remarks": "",
        "awayClass": "",
        "reason": "",
        "addtionalClass": "",
        "disableToggle": false,
        "disabled": true,
        "class": "checkin",
        "checkout": "Anwesend"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kindergarden 2",
    "presence_id": 26,
    "totalChildren": 1,
    "totalCheckinChildren": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Thomas Mueller",
        "daycareComment": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "id": "86900",
        "away": null,
        "checkin": [],
        "additionalDay": false,
        "remarks": "",
        "awayClass": "",
        "reason": "",
        "addtionalClass": "",
        "disableToggle": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "checkout": "Nicht anwesend",
        "class": "notcheckin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kindergarden 3",
    "presence_id": 27,
    "totalChildren": 1,
    "totalCheckinChildren": 0,
    "children": [

    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share your code in stackbiltz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an Observable `filteredChildren$` that emits the filtered children to your `day` objects.

To create `filteredChildren$` you need an Observable of filter values. Add a FormControl to your search bar so you can listen to its value changes. (You have to import `ReactiveFormsModule`)

[Demo (Angular 8, Ionic 4, RxJS 6)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-st9n1q?embed=1&file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts)

[Demo (Angular 5, Ionic 3, RxJS 5.5)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dbu5bw?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)

```html
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Suchen..." [formControl]="filterControl" padding></ion-searchbar>
<ion-grid *ngFor="let day of dayOverViewByGroup$ | async; let i = index" padding>       
  <ion-card *ngFor="let child of day.filteredChildren$ | async; let j = index">
    <h1>{{child.name}}</h1>
  </ion-card>
</ion-grid>
```

```js
export class Component {
  filterControl = new FormControl();
  dayOverViewByGroup$: Observable<any>

  ngOnInit() {
    const filter$: Observable<string> = this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(100), 
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      share() // we use filter$ multiple times so we share a single subscription to the source
    );
    this.dayOverViewByGroup$ = this.fetchData().pipe(
      map(days => days.map(day => (
        {
          ...day,
          // add an Observable that emits an array of filtered children
          filteredChildren$: filter$.pipe(this.filterFrom(day.children))
        }
      )))
    );
  }

  fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    // fetch data from Api
    return of(data);
  }

  filterFrom(children: { name: string }[]) {
    return (filter$: Observable<string>) => filter$.pipe(
      // the filter logic (add your own here)
      map(f => children.filter(child => child.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(f.toLowerCase()) > -1))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, however this project using Angular 5 and rxjs@^5.5.0. I've updated version to rxjs to "^6.5.4". Now I have no clue how to make that API call. I have "this.fetchData(...).pipe is not a function" Maybe my provider is not ready for rxjs code. https://gist.github.com/Verthon/16483676667fa45204f0fb0d17b507d5

Comment: @KrzysztofSordyl You don't have to update RxJS. Updating RxJS v5.5 to RxJS v6 is a bigger step and I don't think Angular 5 and Ionic 3 even support RxJS 6. I added a demo for Angular 5 + Ionic 3 + RxJS 5.5. The code is the same as RxJS 5.5 already supports pipe syntax.